# How to make a program that finds the number of happy numbers between 1 and 1 million

Tags: c++, numbers

I am trying to write code that calculates the right number of happy numbers between 1 and 1 million. What ends up being the result, however, is that either my output window remains blank and keeps on running, or else I get an output of 0, which is not correct. Does anybody have any suggestions? Here's the code that I'm using:

From the main function:

```
for (x = 2; x < 10; x++)                 
{
    if(is_happy(x) == 1)
        happy_number++;
}

  cout << "There are " << happy_number << " happy prime numbers between 1 and 1 million" << endl;
```

Note: happy_number starts off with a value of 0;

Then there's the function that calculates whether or not a number is happy:

```
int is_happy(int x)
{
    int y;
    int ans = 0;
    while (x > 0)
    {
        y = x%10;
        ans += pow(y, 2.0);
        x = x/10;
        ans += pow(x, 2.0);
    }

    return ans;
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You iterate up to 10; `ans` would then be the squares of `2`..`9`, never `==1`..

Comment: For a function like `is_happy`, returning a bool probably makes the most since since the answer should be only `true` or `false`.  Also, using `==1` to check true as often a bad idea (as here) because you don't address `>1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I used Wikipedia.
[Happy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number)

The function named isHappy calculates whether or not the argument is happy. I am not sure if it works right if the argument is a negative integer.

You asked:

> How to make a program that finds the number of happy numbers between 1
>   and 1 million

Function int happyNumbersBetween1_1000000() returns with the number of happy numbers between 1 and 1 000 000.

```
#include <iostream>

int happy(int i){
    int j=0;
    while(i!=0){
        j+=(i%10)*(i%10);
        i-=(i%10);
        i/=10;
    }
    return j;
}

bool isHappy(int i){
    switch(i){
        case 1: return true;
        case 4: return false;
        default: return isHappy(happy(i));
    }
}

int happyNumbersBetween1_1000000(){
    int j=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=1000000; ++i)
        if(isHappy(i)){
            ++j;
           // std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        }
    return j;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i=1; i<100; ++i)
        if(isHappy(i))
            std::cout<<i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<happyNumbersBetween1_1000000()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is a little off in calculating a happy number. It's a cycle that keeps continuing until it reaches `1`, or an infinite loop. A happy number reaches `1`, while an unhappy number reaches `4` and loops forever.

```
bool is_happy(int x) //Let the function determine if the number is happy
{
    if (x <= 0) //Discrimination! Only positive numbers are allowed to experience joy
        return false;
    int result;
    while (x != 1) //If x == 1, it is a happy number
    {
        result = 0;
        while (x) //Until every digit has been summed
        {
            result += (x % 10) * (x % 10); //Square digit and add it to total
            x /= 10;
        }
        x = result;
        if (x == 4) //if x is 4, its a sad number
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You should use it like this:

```
for (int x = 2; x < 10; ++x)
{
    if (is_happy(x)) //Let the function do the logic, we just need true or false
        ++happy_number;
}
```

EDIT: You can see it work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90969d5f60dc6430).

Comment: I used your code. The result I got was 46, in a range of 1 to 100, which is too big.

Comment: @jagwar Woah, really? [It works fine for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef5081375f719e59)

Comment: Are you using CodeBlocks?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you test whether or not x == 4, why not just test it for whether or not x > 1?

Comment: Ah, I think part of the problem is that you're using a vector, while I'm not.

Comment: @jagwar Are you sure it copied exactly? No stray semicolons or anything? When the sequence gets to `4`, it repeats where the cycle eventually reaches `4` again, thereby making an infinite loop. That means it isn't a happy number. `7` is a happy number, even though the first step in the sequence is `49`, which is `> 1`. The `#include <vector>` was accidentally left in there from the last time I used it. Since I don't actually use a `vector`, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hmm...it might have something to do with the fact that you're using vectors, while I'm not.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see your previous comment. I get what you're saying about the vectors.

Comment: @jagwar I removed the unnecessary `#include`s and posted a link to it in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.